# ActiveRecord serialize, is this safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, serialization, yaml

I have a simple ActiveRecord class that logs an event and stores some additional data using the `serialize` method. It has one string column for an event and a text column to store a data object.

```
# DB Columns
#   event => string
#   data  => text
#
class MyLog < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :data

  validates :event, :data, :presence => true

end
```

In my controller I would like to take user submitted information and include it as the data:

```
class ContactFormController < ApplicationController

  def send_message
    ...

    data = {name: params[:name], email: params[:email], message: params[:message]}
    MyLog.create(event: "User submitted contact form", data: data)

    ...
  end
end
```

## Questions

1. The `serialize` method uses YAML by default to store objects like this. Is there a security risk here in the case that a user submits some crafty code that is passed through the parameters? Is there a chance for user submitted Ruby code to be executed when the data field is retrieved and deserialized?
2. My goal is to provide a way to log events from anywhere in my app and store data of any sort about that event. Is there a better way to preform this than what I have set up here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms, it's perfectly fine to serialize anything you want. User data of any kind is acceptable.

This presumes you're patched up to the **absolutely latest** version of Rails 3.2 or 4.0. There have been some issues with YAML and JSON serialization in the past but these have been patched and resolved.

Test your application against known vulnerabilities using a tool like [GemCanary](http://gemcanary.com/) to be sure you're current, and to catch future problems.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Any suggestions on a better way for a general log model that I have laid out here? Or does what I have do the job well enough?

Comment: You'll want to compare YAML, JSON and Marshal for performance and data storage characteristics before you commit to a particular serialization method, as testing with non-trivial amounts of data is always essential to get this sort of thing right. Remember things like your `data` assignment line can be done easily with the [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method: `data = params.slice(:name, :email, :message)`

Comment: A further point of consideration is if it's really necessary to use a serialized column instead of three additional columns for free-form data. Serialization is best for complicated, nested structures of Hash and Array type values, or when the nature of the data is highly unpredictable and basically schemaless.